# Как отключая видимость парента отключать ещё и его дочерные объекты?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть объект состоящий из ещё 2 дочерных объектов объектов. Можно ли как то в скрипте отключить не только парент объект, а ещё и его дочерных. Можно конечно для каждого создать переменную MeshRenderer, но можно ли как то попроще?

Comment: Метод `SetActive(true/false)` на парент объекте подойдет или нужно отключить только `MeshRenderer`?

Comment: Это подходит, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Дочерние объекты отключаются автоматически вместе с парентом.

Comment: Ой)⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀